# How to select dataframe row by index value after groupby

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing, group-by

i am quite new to dataframes.

On my dataframe i applied groupby to calculate mean of similar rows.
Then i want to calculate the difference between two rows (condition is variable tester)

gb_data = short_data.groupby(['Patient_ID','Session_ID','Evaluator','Task','Side','Data_type']).mean()

for i in xrange(len(gb_data)):

```
index_list = gb_data.index[i]
evaluator= index_list[2] 
if evaluator== 1:
    EV2 = gb_data.iloc[1,1:]
    # find matching EV1
```

There are evaluator 1 and 2. So if i see one row of data from evaluator 1 i want to get the matching row for evaluator 2. How can i select this row? I can replace 1 per 2 in the index_list but i am not getting how to call the row with this tupple.

Any help would be welcome.

Thanks in advance

For better understandin:
[image 1: how short_data looks like, ends in frame 100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM7nJ.png)

[image 2: how gb_data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uatoa.png)

Comment: Could you show a minima sample data so that we can reproduce?

Comment: I have added images of the dataframes. Thanks

Comment: Have you ever tried to copy and paste text from an image? I will not type that by hand. You should copy the data as **text** in the question itself. As a new user you should read [ask] to understand what we expect from a [mcve]. And to learn how to copy dataframes data, you could also read [Pandas tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pandas/info).